# C++/Win32 dialog generated from resource not behaving normally

Tags: c++, winapi, dialog, resources

I wrote a resource script for a (modeless) dialog that should contain an edit control (used to show a non-edit log report):

```
IDD_LOG DIALOGEX 10, 10, 300, 200, 0
STYLE WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_BORDER | WS_SYSMENU | DS_CENTER
CAPTION "Last Log Report"
{
    EDITTEXT 301, 0, 0, 250, 180, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_VSCROLL | ES_MULTILINE | ES_READONLY
}
```

When I call up the dialog via the menu using

```
hwndLogDlg = CreateDialog(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_LOG), hwnd, (DLGPROC)LogDlgProc)
```

the following things are not right with it:

1. The dialog window contains an edit control, but there's another edit control with the same size above it all. That edit control seems to be a non-child window.
   Also, when I set the text in the edit control calling `SetDlgItemText(hwndLogDlg, IDDE_LOGTXT, "<Could not load log data>");`, both of them are set.
   *I suspect the resource compiler to see the edit control in the script as both a child of the dialog box and a second time as a separate window, although WS_CHILD is set.*
2. The main window is blocked when the dialog is created, although the dialog is modeless.
3. Clicking the closing button of the dialog window won't cause it to close, even though I call `DestroyWindow(hwndDlg);` on WM_QUIT and WM_DESTROY. Together with the problem of the main window being blocked, the only ways for me to close everything is to close the window from the taskbar or taskmanager.

Message loop:

```
while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
    if (!IsDialogMessage(hwndDlg, &Msg)){
        TranslateMessage(&Msg); 
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }
}
```

Dialog window procedure:

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK LogDlgProc(HWND hwndDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
switch (message){
    case WM_INITDIALOG:{
        hwndLogTxt = GetDlgItem(hwndDlg, IDDE_LOGTXT);

        fileHandler fH;
        if (!fH.init("report.log")){
            SetDlgItemText(hwndLogTxt, IDDE_LOGTXT, "<Could not load log data>");
            err(ERR_CUSTOM,"Failed to extract log file!","Extraction Error!");
        }
        else SetDlgItemText(hwndLogTxt, IDDE_LOGTXT, fH.getStr());
        break;
    }
    case WM_DESTROY:{
        DestroyWindow(hwndDlg);
        break;
    }
}
return true;
}
```

So what I would like to get in the end, is a modeless dialog box containing a (read-only) edit control (that takes up all of the client-area of the dialog window).
Is this problem about my resource syntax or about the way I call it? May I even have been missing necessary steps on WM_INITDIALOG?

Comment: Your code is not behaving correctly. Therefore you have posted the dialog template definition.

Comment: Yeah because the dialog template is pretty much all code I have about the dialog. It might be the message loop too, but that should be correct, since I did like in some other example on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644996(v=vs.85).aspx. Added it to the question now.

Comment: No idea about your phantom edit control (*show your code*) but your call to `SetDlgItemText` is wrong - it takes the **parent** (dialog) handle, not the control handle.

Comment: I accidentally changed the SetDlgItemText() parameter while in the rush of copying over into this question, thanks for the hint. I added the dialog window procedure now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some comments:

a) I suppose you actually used `LogDlgProc` in your call to `CreateDialog()`? do you also have `ShowWindow(hwndDlg, SW_SHOW);` after `CreateDialog()`?

b) your `EDITTEXT` control is declared in the resource file with a number as the id, your logic uses `IDDE_TXT` -- change your dialog resource to have `EDITTEXT IDDE_TXT...`

c) change the code to set your edit control to `SetDlgItemText(hwndDlg, IDDE_TXT, ...);`; make sure that `fH.getStr()` returns the correct string value

d) close `fH` after reading from it if necessary (depending on how `fileHandler` is implemented)

e) return `FALSE` for unhandled messages

f) you won't get a `WM_DESTROY` until you call `DestroyWindow`, I think handling IDCANCEL should be enough

Your dialog proc should look like

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK LogDlgProc(HWND hwndDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{   switch (message)
    {   case WM_INITDIALOG:
        {   fileHandler fH;
            if (fH.init("report.log"))
            {   SetDlgItemText(hwndDlg, IDDE_TXT, fH.getStr());
                // close fH
            }
            else
            {   SetDlgItemText(hwndDlg, IDDE_TXT, "<Could not load log data>");
                err(ERR_CUSTOM,"Failed to extract log file!","Extraction Error!");
            }
            return TRUE;
        }

        case WM_COMMAND: 
            if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL) 
            {   DestroyWindow(hwndDlg);
                return TRUE;
            }
//EDIT start
            if (HIWORD(wParam) == EN_SETFOCUS && LOWORD(wParam) == IDDE_TXT)
            {   SendDlgItemMessage(hwndDlg, IDDE_TXT, EM_SETSEL, -1, -1);
                return TRUE;
            }
//EDIT end

    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: I fixed the variable identifiers now, I had them changed back and forth during posting the question and trying to simplify the situation for the answerers. fileHandler is a class of my own; I suppose if I deallocate dynamic memory in the destructor ~fileHandler(), memory leaks are off the table, or should I implement a deallocating function explicitly? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: deallocating / closing the file handle in the destructor should be ok -- does your dialog box work now?

Comment: Yes, the dialog box works now. I now want to find a way of deselecting my whole edit control content because it gets automatically selected after being assigned the default focus. That's what I know about that yet. And when I minimize the dialog, it somehow hides in the lower left corner of the screen, but is still there, very small. I have changed the dialog style to '(WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW ^ (WS_CAPTION | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX)) | WS_VISIBLE | DS_CENTER'.

Comment: Added code to deselect the contents of the edit box; I normally use dialog style `WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU`

Answer (score 3):

In general, return `FALSE` from the dialog proc to get default processing.

Some messages that logically return a value are however special-cased. You can use the `SetDlgMsgResult` macro from `<windowsx.h>` to handle those special cases correctly. Or you can just ignore them for now.

Also, I suspect you should not call `DestroyWindow`.

Comment: I suppose you're talking of WM_DESTROY not being necessary? I fixed that now after recieving the first answer. If you indeed meant DestroyWindow(), please tell me why.

Comment: `WM_DESTROY` normally tells you that window destruction is ongoing, as a result of some earlier call to `DestroyWindow`. For that normal operation calling `DestroyWindow` in response is meaningless. However, you have not or did not then show all your code, so I'm into assumption-land, what normally is the case.

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks for pointing that out. I guess I was rather expecting my resource script to be wrong, so I didn't want to clutter the question with other code at first.

Comment: Thank you, I know this post is more than 6 years old but that tip to return false from the processing function just solved my 4-hour problem